# Cannot install Wordpress

Tags: software-installation, xampp, wordpress

I cannot install Wordpress in my XAMPP on Ubuntu. What's the proper way?

[image]

Comment: Need a little more info here. What did you try already?

Comment: Try referring to the [Ubuntu server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/wordpress.html)

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is reading the message in the dialog **;)**

Start the installer with `sudo` privileges:

```
sudo ~/Downloads/bitnami-wordpress-4.3.1-0-module-linux-installer.run
```